# R: how to define layout position of nodes

Tags: r, layout, graph, igraph

I have a random graph `g` and need to split this graph into two separated graphs `g1` and `g2` with a rule. The split rule is binary matrix `E`: if (E[i,j]=1) then move the corresponding node to the graph g1, else move the corresponding node to the graph g2. After separation I need to plot three graphs on the screen. I have use the 1s from matrix `E` in order to define position of nodes from graph `g1` on the plot (i.e. `mylayout1`). My code is shown below.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(42)
n <- m <- 5
B <- matrix(sample(0:255, (n*m)^2, replace=T), nrow = n*n, ncol = m*m)
g <- graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
V(g)$name <- as.character(1:(n*m))
E <- matrix(sample(0:1, n*m, replace=T), nrow = m, ncol = n)

# split into two graphs, if (E[i,j]=1) then the node move to g1, else to g2 

vsubgraph <- c(1:length(E))*E
vsubgraph <- vsubgraph[vsubgraph != 0]

g1 <- induced_subgraph(g, vsubgraph)
g2 <- induced_subgraph(g, setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph))

V(g)[vsubgraph]$color <- "green"
V(g)[setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph)]$color <- "yellow"

V(g1)$name <- vsubgraph 
V(g2)$name <- setdiff(V(g), vsubgraph)

V(g1)$color <- "green"
V(g2)$color <- "yellow"

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

# create layout
cx <-rep(1:n, each = m)
cy <-rep(c(1:m), times = n)

mylayout <- as.matrix(cbind(cx, -cy))

plot(g, layout=mylayout,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g)$name, 
          edge.label.cex=.75,
          xlab='Original graph'
     )

cx <- cx * E
cy <- cy * E

cx <- cx[cx != 0]
cy <- cy[cy != 0]

mylayout1 <- as.matrix(cbind(cx, -cy))

plot(g1, layout=mylayout1,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g)$name, 
          edge.label.cex=.75,
          xlab='1st graph'
     )
plot(g2, #layout=mylayout2,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g)$name, 
          edge.label.cex=.75,
          xlab='2nd graph'
     )
```

Could someone please give an idea how to define `mylayout2` for the second graph `g2`? I would like to use the original position of nodes from the `mylayout`. One of solution may be the using matrix `E` again. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use 0s from matrix `E`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible way is:

```
opE <- ifelse(E == 0, 1, 0)

cx <-rep(1:n, each = m)
cy <-rep(c(1:m), times = n)

cx <- cx * opE
cy <- cy * opE

cx <- cx[cx != 0]
cy <- cy[cy != 0]

mylayout2 <- as.matrix(cbind(cx, -cy))

plot(g2, layout=mylayout2,
          vertex.shape = "square",  
          vertex.label = V(g)$name,
          edge.label.cex=.75,
          xlab='2nd graph'
     )
```